# Import csv data in SQL, but cell data contains comma, how do I handle It in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am reading CSV file in SQL with below code. But a cell data which contains comma , is surrounded by " double quotes.
for example csv file

> Customer Address is header, value in CSV is "City name, Country". This is surroned by double quoates. Other columns are in plain text format.

I want to import data from csv but due to this my all data goes to next cell after seperating comma from this cell.

```
    BULK INSERT #TempTable
    FROM 'e:\\filetesting.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
        TABLOCK
    )
```

> All Extensions,123456,,Jhon Doe,,107,0,"City, Country<321>",197,James ,InBound

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? `FORMAT = 'CSV'` is available from SQL Server 2017.

Comment: There's another swich: `FIELDQUOTE = 'quote_characters']` and other options. See: [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). For further details, please see: [Use a format file to bulk import data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Its version is 14.0.

Comment: I *assume* your data is quoted; if it isn't SQL Server can't do anything you need to fix the process that creates the files

Comment: Can you post the actual content of the input CSV file?

Comment: Yes. My data is in quoted.

Comment: Please post sample data - i.e. open the file in text editor and paste the line into the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult without test data, but I'm able to reproduce the issue from the question and a possible solution is the `FORMAT='CSV'` option, available from SQL Server 2017:

CSV file:

```
Address, Customer
"City name, Country", Customer Name
```

Statement:

```
BULK INSERT #TempTable
FROM 'e:\filetesting.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
```

Result:

```
Address              Customer
----------------------------------
City name, Country   Customer Name
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'FORMAT'. Its giving this error. I just installed the sql server managment studio to latest version. It is giving error on format. i copied your content.

Comment: @FaseehHaris What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return? You need SQL Server 2017 (14).

Comment: Thanks, I installed latest version and Its working great.   :)